# HTML form is not calling JS function onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check if all fields are filled when the form is being submitted. But I have noticed that, form without all filled fields is being sent. So, I started to investigate, and even with return false, which means that form is not sent, it is.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form action="addproduct.php" onsubmit="checkinput()" method="post">
        <style> <?php include 'css/addproduct.css'; ?> </style>
            <div class="iRow">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductSKU">Product SKU:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductSKU"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductName">Product Name:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductName"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductPrice">Product Price:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductPrice"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow dvd">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductSize">Product Size:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductSize"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow book">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductWeight">Product Weight:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductWeight"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow furniture">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductDimensions">Product Dimensions:</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductDimensions"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="iRow">
                <div class="lclass"> <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> </div>
                <div class="tclass">
                    <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions" onchange="selectorhandle()">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
                        <option value="Book">Book</option>
                        <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Product" >
            <script>
                <?php include 'js/addproduct.js'; ?> <!-- Adding this javascript for the dynamic form -->
            </script>

        </form>
```

And in addproduct.js I have:

```
function checkinput()
{
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is in the call to the function by **'onsubmit'** attribute

**onsubmit="checkInput()"**  will only call the checkInput() function and submit form without waiting for the checkInput() to finish.

This behaviour of not waiting for a function / step to finish (Asynchronous nature) is inherent to javascript.

The problem can be fixed by explicitly using

`onsubmit="return checkInput()"`

instead of

`onsubmit="checkInput()"`

**Working example for validating input using onsubmit:**

```
<form action="addproduct.php" onsubmit="return checkInput()" method="post">
    <!-- form fields here -->
</form>

<script>
    function checkInput() {
         if( all_input_is_Valid ) {
             return true
         }
        return false
    }
</script>
```

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Thank you! But why there has to be return? What is it changing in the form of behaviour?

Comment: Calling 'checkInput()' will tell Javascript to simply invoke checkInput() and proceed.  However, the use of 'return' will convert the function call into an assignment statement which says, "get the return value of the checkInput() function". This will make sure that Javascript will wait for the function to finish.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="addproduct.php" onsubmit="checkinput()" method="post">
      <div class="iRow">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductSKU">Product SKU:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductSKU"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductName">Product Name:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductName"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductPrice">Product Price:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductPrice"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow dvd">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductSize">Product Size:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductSize"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow book">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductWeight">Product Weight:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductWeight"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow furniture">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="ProductDimensions">Product Dimensions:</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass"> <input type="text" name="ProductDimensions"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="iRow">
          <div class="lclass"> <label for="typeselector">Product Category</label> </div>
          <div class="tclass">
              <select id="typeselector" name="productoptions" onchange="selectorhandle()">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="DVD">DVD-Disc</option>
                  <option value="Book">Book</option>
                  <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Add Product" >
  </form>

  <?php echo '<script src="js/addproduct.js"></script>'; ?>
```

To verify function call, just add alert in addproduct.js

```
function checkinput() {
    alert("Function called")
    return false;
}
```